# Is there an ethertype field in 802.11 header

Tags: header, wifi

I see in the 802.11 header that there is no ethertype field. How is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 802.11 is carrying any higher layer protocol, it's 802.11 header Type/Subtype field will be "Data" (0x20) or "Qos Data" (0x28), and there will usually be a SNAP header (rfc1042) above the 802.11 header which will convey the type of payload (IP, ARP etc.)

It is of course in theory able to carry any layer 2 protocol, and use any LLC header.

Comment: Thank you , that answers my question.