# How to find out encapsulated protocol inside IEEE802.11 Frame?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, raw-sockets, wifi

I'm developing a `IEEE802.11` frame parser program using `libpcap` inside Linux with raw `C`. I can parse `RadioTap` and `IEEE802.11` headers easily but I can't find out the protocol name which is encapsulated inside the `IEEE802.11` MPDU. Unfortunatly there isn't any field in `IEEE802.11` header indicating the encapsulated protocol (like `protocol` field in `Ethernet` header).

Any solution?

Comment: What do you mean with name? b/g/n... can be retrieved on PLCP Sublayer

Comment: @LPs: b/g/n is part of `IEEE802.11` header. I mean `802.11X` in the case of `EAPOL` packets in WPA authentication or any other protocol encapsulated inside the packet.

Comment: I am no expert, but looking into wireshark [sample captures](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures#Wifi_.2F_Wireless_LAN_captures_.2F_802.11) reveals, that there may be a Logical-Link-Control header with SNAP extensions (as indicated by 0xAA) which may contain [ettertype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType) when OID==0x000000 (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork_Access_Protocol))...Good luck!

Comment: Found [a nice picture](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.519.1.29/1/). (And to clarify -- I am talking about 'Data frames' which are recognised with frame control field)

Comment: off-topic because... This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data of `IEEE802.11` data packets is encapsulated in a `LLC` header (See [here](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/19046/when-a-80211-frame-should-contain-a-llc-header)):

> An 802.11 frame should contain an LLC header if, and only if, it's a
>   Data frame. The frame type and subtype are part of the Frame Control
>   field in the MAC header; Data is one of the frame type values (the
>   others are Control and Management). The subtype doesn't matter - all
>   Data frames should contain an LLC header, and no other frames should.

There are two kinds of `LLC` header: 3 bytes, 8 bytes . `IEEE 802.11` uses the second one (See [here](http://www.wildpackets.com/resources/compendium/wireless_lan/wlan_packets)). In that one, the two last bytes of `LLC` header is equivalent to `Ether Type` field in `Ethernet` protocol. So `0x800` for this field means `IPv4` for example.

Answer (score 2):

For `802.11` frames that are encapsulating data, the header type/subtype will be between `0x20` and `0x2F` (although the frame is usually `0x20` (Data) or `0x28` (QoS-Data)). There will be a 5-byte SNAP header which will contain the type of payload (as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233879/is-there-an-ethertype-field-in-802-11-header)). If the OID (first three bytes of the SNAP header) is `0x000000`, then the next two bytes are the Ethernet Type.

The Ethernet Type would be `0x888e` for EAPoL ([source](https://www.vocal.com/secure-communication/eapol-extensible-authentication-protocol-over-lan/)). That is the field you would inspect to know the encapsulated protocol (`0x0800` for IP, `0x0806` for ARP, etc.).

Here is a good Cisco doc on Ethernet types and how you can use them to filter certain protocols: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ibm/vol1/command/reference/fibm_r1/br1fethc.pdf.

Here is a good Cisco doc on wireless sniffer traces that include a description of the `802.11` type/subtype fields: https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/52391/80211-frames-starter-guide-learn-wireless-sniffer-traces.